# How to mask subdomain as domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, subdomain, lamp

Is it possible to to access web with url *example.com* but variables inside php (like SERVER_NAME) would act like *sub.example.com*?

We made wrong decision during development and now we are actually stuck with two separate versions of software. One for example.com and other for automatically generated subdomains. We could reserver one subdomain to act as our main domain, but we don't want that **sub.** example.com part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add some checks, for example:

```
function hasSubdomain($url) {
    $parsed = parse_url($url);
    $exploded = explode('.', $parsed["host"]);
    if(count($exploded) > 2){
       return true;
    }else{
       return false;
    }
}

if(!hasSubdomain($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])){
   $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']="sub.example.com";
}
```

Comment: I am aware of this solution, but it's very dirty. I was hoping for virtualhost or htaccess configuration.
btw your 'IF' statement in the function is quite disturbing. Hope its only written this way to make it easy and straightforward.

Comment: In that case, simply add `ServerName *.example.com`

Comment: This do something different.